# MYSQL - Usage of CASE/IF to display data

Tags: mysql

I have a table1 as below

| ColA | Update | Insert | ColB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Yes | Yes | Get |
| One | Yes | Yes | Put |

I want the output like

| ColA | Check | ColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Update | Get |
| One | Update | Put |
| One | Insert | Get |
| One | Insert | Put |

I have written the below query but it's showing either update data or insert data but not both.

```
select colA,
CASE WHEN update ="Yes" THEN "update"
WHEN insert ="Yes" THEN "insert"
end as check from Table1;
```

Please help me in achieving the above output as expected, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ColA, 'Update' Check, ColB
FROM Table1
WHERE `Update` = 'Yes'
UNION ALL
SELECT ColA, 'Insert' Check, ColB
FROM Table1
WHERE `Insert` = 'Yes';
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE is not going to produce two rows where you only have one.  Either use a union, or join an ad hoc table to check separately for updates and inserts:

```
select colA, check, colB
from (
    select 'update' as check union all select 'insert'
) check
join Table1 on
    case check
        when 'update' then Update='Yes'
        when 'insert' then Insert='Yes'
    end
```

This essentially loops twice over table1, once looking for updates and once for inserts.